# How to prevent reflow for a part of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, html-rendering, blink, reflow

Under which circumstances does the browser engine (e.g. chromium blink) ignore some part of the render tree when reflowing?

For example, `updatedNode` has been updated in a way that reflow has to be triggered (e.g. `position: absolute; left:0px` changed to `position: absolute; left:10px`). Thats okay; it's okay that `daughterNode` contains some large table which needs to be reflowed. However, `brotherNode` and contains a large svg with 10000 dom elements.

Is is there a way to prevent reflow for `brotherNode`?`

If possible, is there a way to prevent reflow in `daughterNode`, too?

```
                    root
                     ^
                     |
                     +
                 parentNode
                  ^  ^  ^
  +---------------+  |  +---------------+
  +                  +                  +
sisterNode      updatedNode     brotherNode
                   ^   ^
               +---+   +----+
               +            +
           daughterNode   sonNode
```

Comment: Did you try applying `position: absolute` or `position:fixed` to the `brotherNode`?

Comment: `parentNode` has position `absolute`, but `brotherNode` not explicitly, but inherited it from the parent. Will `position:absolute` be used as "early exit" for the reflow?